# Clase activa se resetea

Tags: javascript, html5, css

En el siguiente Script muy simple. Por que después de pasar a Activo y colorearlo del color deseado, una vez terminada la carga de la vista, se resetea el activo al item activo por Default? que estará pasando.

HTML

```
<div class="list-group">
<a class="list-group-item active" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Sistema")"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Inicio</a> 
<a class="list-group-item" href="@Url.Action("Users", "Sistema")"><i class="fa fa-user-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Usuarios</a>
<a class="list-group-item" href="@Url.Action("Ajustes", "Sistema")"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Ajustes</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    //Elementos de la Lista
    var Items = $(".list-group a");

    // manejador de click sobre todos los elementos
    Items.click(function () {

        // eliminamos active de todos los elementos
        Items.removeClass('active');

        // activamos el elemento clicado.
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.active {
    background: #337AB7;
}
```

Comment: @sioesi No, el Nav esta en un _Layout, nada lo recarga mas que cuando se carga la pagina

Answer (score 0):

En el HTML de la vista estableces que siempre se muestre como opción activa la primera:

```
<a class="list-group-item active" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Sistema")">
```

Cuando pulsan en cualquier otro link estableces la clase active para ese link, con lo que se modifica su aspecto. Pero también navegas a la página seleccionada.

Al navegar a la nueva página se vuelve a renderizar la vista con el menú y por tanto vuelve a ponerse como activa la primera opción.

Al renderizar el menú deberías establecer como activa la opción de la página que se está mostrando, no siempre la primera.

Comment: El menu esta en un _Layout no se recarga.. o al menos según yo, agregue items vacíos y para estos si se queda el efecto..

Comment: Si para navegar no utilizas Ajax estás cargando de nuevo la página completa, por lo que el el layout se renderiza de nuevo también

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio mucho tu apoyo, al final se tuvo que agregar mediante codigo en el controlador.